# DataTables Custom filter Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, flask, datatable

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно передать значения из кастомных полей на серверную часть посредством `Ajax`  `DataTables`

основной скрипт для формирования таблицы:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var empDataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'ajax': {
                'url':'/file',
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    return $.extend( {}, d, {
                        "choice": $("#selected_volume").val(),
                    } );
                }},
            'lengthMenu': [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            searching: false,
            sort: false,
            'columns': [
                { data: 'country' },
                { data: 'brand' },
                { data: 'volume' },
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

соответсвенно костомное поле:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selected_volume').dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

пытался передать значения через данный блок, к сожалению, попытки не увенчались успехом

```
'ajax': {
                    'url':'/file',
                    "data": function ( d ) {
                        return $.extend( {}, d, {
                            "choice": $("#selected_volume").val(),
                        } );
                    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

рабочий вариант в моем случае оказался следующим:

```
'ajax': {
                'url':'/file',
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    return $.extend( {}, d, {
                        'volume': $('#selected_volume').val(),
                        'brand': $('#selected_brand').val(),
                        'country': $('#selected_country').val()
                    } );
                }
                },





 oTable = $('#table_hlr').DataTable();
        $('#selected_volume').change(function (e) {
            oTable.draw();
        });
        oTable = $('#table_hlr').DataTable();
        $('#selected_brand').change(function (e) {
            oTable.draw();
        });
        oTable = $('#table_hlr').DataTable();
        $('#selected_country').change(function (e) {
            oTable.draw();
        });
```